# Reverse engineering risk when using Firestore with mobile native app (React native)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Developing an application of IOS, Android using React native.
The Firebase SDK uses this.
https://rnfirebase.io

Suppose you allow all Firestore security rules.

If the native application is reverse-engineered, will anyone be ready to read and write Firestore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't do anything with security rules, then all someone needs in order to read and write all your data is the name of your project.  This is readily available by anyone looking at the contents of your APK or API, since it's not encrypted.

Even if you did encrypt that data, anyone looking at your APK or IPA will be able to see the code used to decrypt it.

You really need to use security rules to protect your users' data.

Comment: Thanks!

Implementing the user authentication function of the native application on its own, and trying to store only a part of data in Firestore.

Do I need to also use Firebase Authentication to read and write Firestore only from the native application I developed?

(Can not write Firestore "rules" without using "Firebase Authentication"?)

Comment: In other words, if  have own authentication function without using Firebase Authentication, how should Firestore's rules be written?

Comment: You can't.  Use Firebase Auth.

Comment: Are they serious . .
Thank you!

Comment: That's the nature of mobile application development.

Answer (score 0):

If you reverse engineered android app than you will get `google-services-json` file which is the **basic** and **most important**  asset to connect to firebase.

As I can read RN-firebase documentation its a light-weight layer on-top of the native Firebase SDKs (iOS & Android) meaning it's just provide you with the methods to access already defined firebase services.

One thing you can do to protect your code is by using an *encryption library* to encode the JS and decode it at runtime before passing it to the bridge. The problem is that you'd have to ship the decryption key with the app code, so it would be trivial for a hacker to decrypt it if they were inclined to do so.

Comment: Assume used the native Firebase SDK (iOS and Android) instead of React native.
Is that case secure?

Comment: RN uses native firebase sdk only. It's just like calling a native method from a JS file